# Define global firebase constant in Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, service-worker

I have a service worker written in Typescript that does this:

```js
export default null;
declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;
declare const firebase: any // ### FIX THIS. This needs to be typed as firebase ####

// the imports below expose firebase global object
self.importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-app.js');
self.importScripts(
  'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-messaging.js'
);

self.addEventListener('install', function () {
  // do stuff here.
  firebase.initializeApp();
});
```

It's defining `firebase` as a const of type `any`. I want it to be the same type one gets by doing

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

I would like to **not** import/bundle firebase in my service worker, because that significantly bloats my service worker. The import scripts already expose everything I need (i.e., they expose a global `firebase` for me).

I was doing this before, but webpack makes the file from 800 bytes to 80kb.

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

**How can I get the types of `firebase` without importing all the code that comes with `firebase/app`?**

I've tried this:

```js
export default null;
declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;
/// <reference types="firebase/app" />
declare const firebase: firebase;
```

But I get the error `Cannot use namaespace 'firebase' as a type.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked!

```js
import type firebasetypes from 'firebase/app';
declare const firebase: typeof firebasetypes;

firebase.initializeApp({...});
firebase.messaging().onBackgroundMessage(...);
```